# Chrome WebDriver launch directly to URL instead of new tab page - Python, Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch Chrome WebDriver using Selenium directly to a URL instead of launching to my default homepage (Chrome's new tab page) first and then calling `driver.get(url)`. Is this possible?

I wasn't able to find a command-line argument to pass that would make the driver launch directly to a specified URL.  Does this command line argument exist?

I then tried to alter my homepage in the initialization of the driver via few different methods found online of adding a dict containing key 'homepage' and value 'desired_url' to the driver's "prefs", but none of these methods worked for me.

If there is no way to do this from the driver itself, how can I change my Chrome homepage from a Python program prior to launching the driver?

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

--homepage= "url"

Command line argument

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('homepage=url')
options.add_argument('no-startup-window') 
webDriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: This did change my homepage, but Chrome WebDriver still loaded the 'new tab' page first instead of the homepage.  When I press the home button, it does go to the page specified in options.add_argument().  Do you know how launch directly to the specified URL? Thanks!

Comment: Why you want to do that ?

Comment: --no-startup-window , passing this argument will stop the new window from opened

Comment: Added that to answer

Comment: I want the window to open directly to the specified URL without first going to Chrome's default new tab page (which has a google search bar and frequently visited sites) to avoid the extra time this takes.  Launching directly to specified URL would save time.  --no-startup-window just caused no window at all to launch, so I think you misunderstood me.

Comment: with "no-startup-window" selenium cant even start -> https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5351
the 'homepage=url' doesnt do the trick.

The problem only occurs if you specify a user-data-dir/profil. without out a profil it works as expected.